# How to create custom token with email and password in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm developing a custom authentication using firebase and my own server.

Workflow:

User sends his email and password to my server.

In the server, I should create a custom token and send him back, but,

```
createCustomToken(uid)
```

Accepts only uid and not email and password.
So, I have to grab the uid(I guess) by email using:

```
getUserByEmail(email)
```

After that, I get the user data.(uid, password(hashed), salt, etc..)

Which script should I use to hash the pass sent by the user to compare with the one sent by firebase?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Custom tokens are mainly used to integrate client apps with custom authentication systems. To authenticate with email and password, simply use the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` function provided in the client SDKs (e.g. [web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password), [android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password)).

Comment: Also note that the user record returned by `getUser()` in the Admin SDK does not have a password hash on it, so you cannot implement the above suggested flow anyway.